# Rotated xtable colnames with Tufte_handout in RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, xtable

I need to rotate the column names in a Tufte_handout in RMarkdown, and I think "\usepackage{rotating}" is missing. But no matter how I try, I can't get it in without errors.

Here is a working example (reduced version of template in RStudio). The two first tables are plotted (without rotated colnames), but when "#" is removed in the last two tables with rotated colnames, it fails.

````
---
title: "Tufte Handout with rotated tables"
output: rmarkdown::tufte_handout
---

# Table from RStudio template

```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
options(xtable.booktabs = TRUE)
xtable(head(mtcars[,1:6]), caption = "Ok. Template from RStudio.")
```

# Modified table (working)

```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
options(xtable.booktabs = TRUE)
the.table <- xtable(head(mtcars[,1:6]), caption = "Also ok.")
print((the.table), rotate.colnames=FALSE)
```

# Modified table (not working)

```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
options(xtable.booktabs = TRUE)
options(xtable.rotate.colnames = TRUE)
# Next row will fail
#xtable(head(mtcars[,1:6]), caption = "Not ok.")
```

# Modified table (not working)

```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
options(xtable.booktabs = TRUE)
the.table <- xtable(head(mtcars[,1:6]), caption = "Not ok.")
# Next row will fail.
#print((the.table), rotate.colnames=TRUE)
```
````

Update: Thanks to @Jonathan's patient support, I finally got it working. These are the steps:

1. Created new project in RStudio: enhancedtufte (as a package)
2. Created diretory inst under enhancedtufte
3. Created directory rmarkdown under inst
4. Created directory templates under rmarkdown
5. Ran command "system.file("rmarkdown/templates/tufte_handout", package="rmarkdown")" to find where original tufte_handout is, and copied directory "tufte_handout" (from under templates) to the templates-directory created in previous step
6. Edited line in template.yaml from "name: Tufte Handout" to "name: Tufte Handout 2"
7. Clicked "Build & Reload" in RStudio
8. Selected File -> New File -> R Markdown..., and then From Template -> Tufte Handout 2 {enhancedtufte}
9. In new document, changed line "output: rmarkdown::tufte_handout" to "output:enhanced_tufte::tufte_handout"
10. Copied all files from https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/tree/master/R to enhancedtufte/R
11. Edited package name to "enhancedtufte in tufte_handout.R "# get the tufte handlout template
    template <-  system.file(
    "rmarkdown/templates/tufte_handout/resources/tufte-handout.tex", 
    package = "enhancedtufte"
    )"
12. Added "\usepackage{rotating}" in tufte-handout.tex
13. Build & Reload
14. Knit works with sideways table (remove # in example above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\usepackage` directive needs to go into the TeX template that Pandoc uses.

Unfortunately it's not extremely easy to change the template, but it's not impossible. Here's what you need to do:

1. Create a new package in RStudio (say, enhanced_tufte).
2. Copy rmarkdown's Tufte handout template to your package. You can find the location of the Tufte handout template with this command: `system.file("rmarkdown/templates/tufte_handout", package="rmarkdown")`; you'll want to copy this folder to your package's `inst/rmarkdown` folder.
3. Modify your package's copy of `tufte-handout.tex` to include `\usepackage{rotating}`; build and load your package.
4. Modify your YAML header to use your new template: `output: enhanced_tufte::tufte_handout`.

[image: sideways headers]

You can also just modify RMarkdown's template directly to include `\usepackage{rotating}`, but of course that'll get reverted the next time you install the rmarkdown package.

Comment: Thanks, followed instructions (but new package name enhancedtufte instead of enhanced_tufte), and can choose edited template when creating new RMarkdown document, but when pressing knit button get error: 'tufte_handout' is not an exported object from 'namespace:enhancedtufte'

Comment: In your package's `NAMESPACE` file, add the line: `export(tufte_handout)`.

Comment: Ok, just did it and got this: Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : undefined exports: tufte_handout
Error: loading failed
Execution halted

Comment: Ah, right ... your package needs the `tufte_handout` function. In your package's `R/` folder, you can add a copy of the R Markdown copy of `tufte_handout.R`: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/24ad9a67ede1a16ce6dbc9a447bd201925fb1415/R/tufte_handout.R